# Convert the strings to UTF-16 Encoding C#

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding, urlencode

I have few strings which are 1252 ENCODED ,UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoded. Ultimately I have to convert all the strings to UTF-16 encoding for comparison,how do I do this?
I came across if we know source encoding we can convert to destination encoding,but I need to convert strings(which may be encoded in any format) to UTF-16(default)

```
 var url=@"file:///C:/Users/Œser/file.html";
Uri parsedurl;
var pass=Uri.TryCreate(url.Trim(),UriKind.Absolute,out parsedurl);
```

At this point parsedurl.AbsoluteUri prints file:///C:/Users/    %C5%92ser/file.html  which is expected

Then I load the html file in IE WebBrowserControl
I intercept navigate
strURL = URL.ToString();
Now strURL prints file:///C:/Users/%8Cser/file.html

Comment: If you have some bytes which represent a string, but you don't know that encoding is being used, you cannot turn those bytes into a string. You can have a guess, by e.g. looking for a BOM, but it's going to be very hard to tell the difference between some bytes which represent a string in UTF8-without-BOM and some bytes which represent a string in 1252

Comment: .NET strings are *always* UTF-16 (at least until `Utf8String`, which is looking like .NET 7 or .NET 8 now); do you mean that you have some *bytes* that are 1252 ENCODED ,UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoded, and you want to read them into `string` values for each?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes the strings internally are converted to 1252,UTF-8 and converted to string object, I need the string object back to be converted to UTF-16

Comment: @rac10 strings *are* UTF-16; I can guarantee you that the `string` instances aren't 1252, UTF-8, or anything else

Comment: with the edit: you're talking about something *very* different to text encoding such as UTF-16 etc - you're talking about Uri %-encoding; *completely* different topic; it sounds like the real problem here is: "IE WebBrowser Control is using an unexpected codepage for unicode uris, instead of using UTF8 %-encoding" - for *that*, I suspect there might be few remedies - ultimately IE (and thus IE WebBrowser Control) is dead, obsolete, deprecated, null, void, nix and also did I say: dead?

Comment: So is there no way to convert to UTF16 without knowing source encoding?

Answer (score 1):

.NET `string` values are always UTF-16 (at least until `Utf8String`, which is looking like .NET 7 or .NET 8 now). So presumably you have some *bytes* or *streams* that are encoded in various encodings, that you want to covert to UTF-16 `string` instances.

The key here is `Encoding`; for example:

- `var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);`
- `var enc = Encoding.UTF8`
- `var enc = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;` (UTF-16, big-endian)
- `var enc = Encoding.Unicode;` (UTF-16, little-endian)

You can use this encoding manually (`GetString(...)`, `GetEncoder(...)` etc) - or you can pass it to a `TextReader` such as `StreamReader` as an optional constructor argument.

Note that 1252 may not be available in .NET Core / .NET 5 (only .NET Framework), as it depends on the OS encoding directory. You may have to settle for "Western European (ISO)" (iso-8859-1, code-page 28591 i.e. `Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)`).

From https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html:

> ISO-8859-1 (also called Latin-1) is identical to Windows-1252 (also called CP1252) except for the code points 128-159 (0x80-0x9F). ISO-8859-1 assigns several control codes in this range. Windows-1252 has several characters, punctuation, arithmetic and business symbols assigned to these code points.

Similarly, `Encoding` can be used to *write* to any chosen encoding, if you want to get bytes again - presumably using either of the UTF-16 variants.

Comment: The problem I am facing is strings get converted Œ from %C5%92 to 1252 equivalent  %8C

Comment: @rac10 I think you need to be *very* careful about defining the problem here; Œ is indeed represented by decimal 140 (hex 8C) in 1252, and is unicode code-point hex 0152, which is hex C592 in UTF-8 - so... it sounds like everything is working correctly? you'd need to *very clearly* specify your inputs and expected outputs to get more advice on that; also note that this is in the range that is *different* between 1252 and iso-8859-1, so: you're going to need to be very careful if you're using .NET Core

Comment: I am loading html file where the file name has characters like Œ (UTF-8 ENCODING ,I am using URI), I load the file name in IE WebBrowserControl and intercept navigate and read again file name,now the file name has 1252 encoding

Comment: file *names* are very different again; I doubt we're talking about the *name* here, and any .NET API talking about file *names* is going to be a `string`, with any encoding issues outside of your view; again, what we really need here is code that illustrates the exact problem you're having (with the minimum of dependencies), that shows the inputs, current outputs, and the expected outputs. It is impossible to comment further without this. I'm not trying to be a pain, but the details **really, really matter** when you start talking about encoding problems.

Comment: Let me know if u need additional info